# Vercel doesn't send emails. It works fine locally

Tags: javascript, email, vercel

Locally the response code from resend is logged and the mail is sent. On Vercel, the last thing logged is the subject. I also tried with nodemailer - same thing. Is it at all possible to sent emails from vercel's free account ?

```
export const sendEmail = async (to: string, subject: string, html: string) => {
    try {
        console.log('sendEmail - resend')
        console.log('to', to)
        console.log('subject', subject)
        const resend = new Resend(process.env.RESEND_KEY)
        const response: CreateEmailResponse = await resend.emails.send({
            from: process.env.SMTP_FROM_EMAIL!,
            to: to,
            subject: subject,
            html: html
        })
        console.log('CreateEmailResponse', response)
        return response
    } catch (error) {
        console.log('send mail error', error)
        throw error
    }
}
```

Regards Ole

I saw that the PRO account has email support, so I upgraded to PRO TRIAL, but it is the same thing. I will try to upgrade to PRO. I don't know if it will help though.

Answer (score 0):

You should add the following code to your function:

export const runtime = 'edge';
export const dynamic = 'force-dynamic';

As the bellow example:

https://resend.com/docs/send-with-vercel-edge-functions